# I want to get the Page Number of Foo Table for Server Side Processing

Tags: javascript, jquery, footable

This is my foo table code I can get when Pagination button is clicked  want to get the page number of the button click in java script can anyone please help me with this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.footable').footable();
    // $('.footable2').footable();
    $('.footable').footable().bind({
        'footable_paging': function (e) {
            paginateScroll();
        }
    });
});

function paginateScroll() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".footable").offset().top
    }, 100);
    console.log('pagination button clicked'); //remove after test
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working uses this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.footable').footable();
    $('.footable').footable().bind({
        'footable_paging': function (e) {
            paginateScroll();
        }
    });


});

function paginateScroll() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".footable").offset().top
    }, 100);
    $("a").click(function () {
        var number = $(this).text();
      
    });
}
```